# RavenDB 4 and Identities Id

Tags: ravendb, identity, transactional, ravendb4

I just upgraded a project from RavenDB 3.5 to 4.0 and one of the biggest change I noticed is the way they change the way Ids are generated.

In my project most of the collections have a basic id structure like "[collection name]/[progressive id]", where the progressive id is an integer, and not the new default "[progressive]-[node]".
Following the [documentation](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.0/csharp/client-api/document-identifiers/working-with-document-identifiers) I specified the pattern id for new documents as "[collection name]|" and is actually generating unique/progressive/integer ids.

The problem is when I've to save transactionally 2 or more documents and reference them between themselves. Let's say I've two kind of object:

User entity

```
{
    "Id": "users/1",
    ...
}
```

User address entity

```
{
    "Id": "userAddresses/1",
    "UserId": "users/1",
    ...
}
```

Where in the second document I need to reference the first one via the UserId field.

Before the version 4.0 I was able, in the same transaction, to do something like:

```
User newUser = new User();

session.Store(newUser)

UserAddress newUserAddress = new UserAddress();
newUserAddress.UserId = newUser.Id;

session.Store(newUserAddress);

session.SaveChanges();
```

After the **session.Store(newUser)** if I accessed the **newUser.Id** property I was able to see the generated Id. Now I just see "users|", I've to wait after the SaveChanges() to see the generated Ids.

This behaviour seems to happen only for Identities Ids, if I use the id structure "[collection name]/[progressive]-[node]" I'm able to see the generated id right after the Store().

Is it by design? Is there a way to force the old behaviour? 
OR How can I manage transactionally a situation like this one using progressive/integer ids?

Answer (score 3):

In RavenDB v4.0 you have the same behavior. After you call to `session.Store(entity)`, or `await session.StoreAsync(entity)` for the async session, you should have the `entity.Id` filled with the ID.

It is setting the ID using the HiLo approach, which you can read about it here:
https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.0/Csharp/server/kb/document-identifier-generation#hilo-algorithm

The only difference in RavenDB v4.0 that the ID would be like: `users/1-A` instead of `users/1` in the previous versions.

Comment: This is the problem: I need it to work also for identities ids. I already tested the default pattern and is working as before. But as I use the "users" pipe format to have just integers, is not working anymore...

Comment: @tanathos As in 3.5, when using identities, you have to wait for the `SaveChanges` call. If you want to use numeric ids without the node's tag, you can use `AsyncHiLoIdGenerator` and then override `GetDocumentIdFromId`, see https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb/blob/7823c5f1f0362072f1e051e38e3eb6fb76c9d06a/src/Raven.Client/Documents/Identity/AsyncHiLoIdGenerator.cs#L45

Comment: @AyendeRahien Thank you for the answer, I'll try this way so. Anyway is strange what you said, I'm certain in 3.5 after the Store() I already had my progressive Id (generated with the pattern "[collection]/"). My application would have not work at all otherwise. Is it possibly related to some configuration?

Comment: I wrote the relevant code, if you used `collection/`, it was only available after `SaveChanges()`.